# handling string input without ' '

Tags: python-3.x

Trying to print after string as input incorrectly e.g. without quotations ''

```
while True:
    t=eval(input("number "))
    if isinstance(t, str):
        print("bad")
    if TypeError: #trying to detect strings not input in ' ' format
        print("bad")
```

the expected result would be to print "bad" when 'string' or string is input in the console.
 However, when inputing a string without quotations my code breaks. Not sure how to detect for inputs without quotations.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you want to consume a number from command line and you are trying to check if instead you received a string.

`eval()` will evaluate its arguments as if it was some recognized python code, simply speaking. [See documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval). If you pass string, eval is trying to evaluate `string`, which isn't really python code. So, an error is thrown. If you pass `'string'`, eval believes it is a quoted string.

What you probably need is this:

```
while True:
    t = input("number ")

    try:
        my_value = int(t)
    except:
        if t == 'quit':
            break
        else:
            print('I didnt receive a string. Please try again');
            continue

    print('Great! Received a number')
```

That way, you ask for information from the user. You will get a string. Then, you try to convert it to an integer. If that fails, you can check if the user provided `quit`. If so, stop the program. If not, tell the user you got a string and you want a number.

If you got a number, great, you can proceed further.

Comment: Thanks for the help... the code is working much better now. I just have one final question if you feel like answering it! If I input a string in the quotations form, it will not print anything, just continue to solicit a new input. do you know how i can fix this so it will print when a string is inputted with quotations?

Comment: Give me an example. What would you type when prompted to enter a number and what would you like the program to do with it?